# iOS: Change price tier of InAppPurchase programatically on first sale (sell IAP limit times to ALL users?)

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I never worked with `IAP` yet, but I couldn't find information for the following scenario:

**Example:** Take an ios-app-game where `User A` buys a sword for price tier 1. The sword is still available, but `User B` has to buy it for price tier 2. `User C` for price tier 3 .... And if the sword reaches price tier 10, it disappear from the in-app purchase list. That means, in the whole game this sword appears maximum 10 times..

Is this possible? Or is the limitation to such a scenario with apples in-app purchase api not possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to define 10 different IAP products and use your own server to know which have been sold (and thus which should be displayed). It would be your responsibility to manage all of this interaction and what is displayed. The only interaction with Apple is to actually get the product details and action the purchases.